# Compiling Spark from Github

Tags: dart, google-chrome-app

I am trying to compile Spark IDE for chrome apps from https://github.com/dart-lang/spark/tree/master/ide. Steps

- Opened chrome://flags and enabled experimental api
- Opened chrome://extensions and "Load unpacked extension" pointed to the local folder for the above code.

The app loads. On loading it is stuck with a loading animation forever

Comment: Does it work in Dartium for you? Are you actually talking about running in Dartium or building to JavaScript so it can run in Chrome?

Answer (score 2):

For running in Dartium you need to point to the app directory not the package directory.
You also need to run `grind setup` to copy the application to the app directory as the readme here says https://github.com/dart-lang/spark/tree/master/ide

I'm not sure this experimental settings are still necessary (probably not if you use a Dart development build which already includes Dartium 36)

For building to JavaScript you run `pub build` in the package directory and load the extension from build/web/app (normally it is done this way, not sure if this really works with Spark, haven't tried it myself yet)

Comment: To add to Gunter's answer, to run it in Dartium, use `./grind setup` and load the app/ directory as an unpacked extension. In Chrome, run `./grind deploy`, and load build/deploy-out/web/ as an unpacked extension. Our directory structure is a bit convoluted right now; it's organized for when Chrome Apps could not load resources from symlinks. They can now, so when we eventually re-organize it, the app structure will look much closer to a typical dart project layout.

Comment: @DevonCarew I only found `./grind setup` but not `./grind deploy` in your readme. Have I overlooked it or should this be added?